# Access canvas in loop easeljs

Tags: html, canvas, easeljs

I am using easeljs for HTML5 programming. In my example i have 3 canvas(can1,can2,can3 are the Stage of those three canvas and have to load images in that canvas using loop

Eg:

```
can1 = new Stage(canvas1);
can2 = new Stage(canvas2);
can3 = new Stage(canvas3);
for(var j=0;j<=3;j++){ 
  "can"+j.addChild(//image need to display)
}
```

"can"+j not working. It show j.addChild is not function error. How to access this?

Thanks,
sathya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your canvases in a array, then access them, like this:

```
var can = [new Stage(canvas1),
           new Stage(canvas2),
           new Stage(canvas3)];
for(var j=0;j<=3;j++){ 
    can[j].addChild(//image need to display);
}
```

The reason this didn't work is because you can't build variable names like that. `"can"+j` will just return a string, `"can1"`, which doesn't have a `addChild` function.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the good answer that Cerbrus gave, this jsFiddle shows you how to use easeljs to display your images in their own separate canvas elements using a loop:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/gxrSQ/

Also notice in this line of code, your can1 variable is actually a Stage object--not a canvas:
can1=new Stage(canvas1);

Here is the script that loops through an array of imageUrls and uses easeljs to load the images into separate canvas elements:

```
    var images=[];
    var stages=[];
    // create an array to hold the path to each image
    images.push("yourImage1.png");
    images.push("yourImage2.png");
    images.push("yourImage3.png");
    // call  a function to load each of the images you pushed into images[]        
    loadImages();

    function loadImages(){
        // loop thru images
        for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
            // create a new canvas for this image
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", "can"+i);
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            stages.push(i);
            // create a new image object 
            var img=new Image();
            img.index=i;
            // important! -- wait until the image has been loaded
            img.onload=function(e){
                // get the canvas element for this image
                // and set the canvas.width and canvas.height
                var c=document.getElementById("can"+this.index);
                c.setAttribute("width",this.width);
                c.setAttribute("height",this.height);
                // create a new stage using this new canvas
                var stage=new createjs.Stage(c);
                // create a bitmap to feed into the new stage
                var bmp=new createjs.Bitmap(this);
                // add the bitmap to the stage
                stage.addChild(bmp);
                // update the stage (the image will display now)
                stage.update();
                // save this new stage in an array 
                // in case you need it later
                stages[this.index]=stage;
            }
            // set the image source from the images array
            img.src=images[i];
        }
    }
```